# How to check the convergence of a complex series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

Consider the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{nz}}{1+e^{nz}}$ where $z \in \mathbb{C}$. Does this series converge?
I tried to use Cauchy root test but $\lim_{n \to \infty}(\frac{e^{nz}}{1+e^{nz}})^{\frac{1}{n}}=1$. Do you have any hint?

Comment: Write $w = e^z$. It's probably easier to see what's going on in that form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f_m(z)
=\sum_{n=1}^{m} \frac{e^{nz}}{1+e^{nz}}\\
=\sum_{n=1}^{m} \frac{1+e^{nz}-1}{1+e^{nz}}\\
=\sum_{n=1}^{m} 1-\sum_{n=1}^{m} \frac{1}{1+e^{nz}}\\
=m-\sum_{n=1}^{m} \frac{1}{1+e^{nz}}\\
$

The sum converges for
$\Re(z) > 0$
so $f_m(z)$ diverges for
these as $m \to \infty$.

Comment: And of course the series converges when $\text{Re}(z)<0$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: It is not true that the $n$'th root tends to $1$ for every $z\in\mathbb{C}$, and when it does, the general term does not converge to zero so the series diverges in that case.

Comment: The series converges for $\text{Re}(z)<0$.